# How can I style two inline-block divs so the tops of each are in line?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="testDetail1" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="gridBody">
            <div>A</div>
            <div>A</div>
            <div>A</div>
            <div>A</div>
            <div>A</div>
            <div>A</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="testDetail2" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="gridBody">
            <div>B</div>
            <div>B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The two blocks line up at the bottom. I tried adding align: vertical but it does not seem to work. How Can I make it so they align at the top?

Comment: You need to understand the basics of CSS at least. There is no such as style  `style="flex"` and `align: vertical`

Comment: Sorry I removed the flex. That was just one of my experiments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`align: vertical` is not correct: use `vertical-align: top;` for the `div` with `display: inline-block` applied.

```
div[id^="testDetail"] {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```